# How to debug .NET geocoding code

Tags: google-maps

Apologies in advance, I really feel that I should be able to solve this myself but am under pressure and not making progress.

1. I need to upgrade an old website that was using mainly classic ASP & googlemaps, now that googlemaps has moved to v3 & deprecated v2.
2. I have a reasonable understanding of the googlemaps api and have resolved the map display, info windows and geofence circle display.
3. I now am having problems upgrading the geocoding of addresses; my issue is that these pages were written by a different developer a long time ago in VB.NET which I have no experiance of :(
4. Unfortunately I dont have a development environment, so am changing the server code (not ideal, but not many users and certainly not at the weekend, and am keeping back ups of each page etc).
5. I see the relevant .aspx and .vb pages but I cant find the code that references the relevant Googlemap geocode functions that I need to change.

I see the code which takes an address or postcode in the textbox and uses Googlemaps to look up the LatLng:

```
Dim gAPIHttp As New GoogleAPICaller
Dim geofenceResults As New Dictionary(Of Integer, GeocodeResults())

Dim results() As GeocodeResults
results = gAPIHttp.GeocodeAddress(txt.Text.Trim & " UK")
geofenceResults.Add(geofenceResultCount, results)
```

and can see some of these defined as strutures in teh object browser, but cant for the life of me really understand where it does the actual geocoding via a request such as:          http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=true_or_false.

Any tips on trying to figure out where to look or help debug are very welcome!

Comment: Looks like `GoogleAPICaller` is custom.  Have you identified that class in a source code file?

Comment: AH! You're a STAR. I cant believe I couldn't find that before. There is a App_Code directory at the parent level (which I assume is standard in a .NET app) which includes a file with the reference. So can I just change this code, or is there some compiling needed somehow?

Comment: Glad I could be of assistance.  Not too sure about `App_Code` vb classes recompiling after change, just give it a try...

Comment: Yep, could just change the vb code & the associated xml parsing (as the googlemaps xml response had changed in v3). THANKS